# K8S Service account unable to get storageclasses

Tags: kubernetes

**Problem**

I'm not able to allow couchbase service account in particular namespace of K8S to get storageclass information.

**My Trail and Error**

Firstly, I try to provisioning Couchbase by using Couchbase operator and the following error was throw.

```
kubectl apply -f cma/couchbase/deployment/06-couchbase-cluster.yaml
secret/cb-auth unchanged
Error from server: error when creating "cma/couchbase/deployment/06-couchbase-cluster.yaml": admission webhook "couchbase-operator-admission.couchbase-dev.svc" denied the request: validation failure list:
storage class "cpt-vshpere-with-tanzu-storage-policy" must exist
storage class "cpt-vshpere-with-tanzu-storage-policy" must exist
storage class "cpt-vshpere-with-tanzu-storage-policy" must exist
storage class "cpt-vshpere-with-tanzu-storage-policy" must exist
```

Look like there is some issue with `storageclass` so I check with this command

```
kubectl get storageclass

NAME                                    PROVISIONER              RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
cpt-vsphere-with-tanzu-storage-policy   csi.vsphere.vmware.com   Delete          Immediate           true                   39d
```

there is storageclass in the k8s, so I try another command to check service account authorization

```
kubectl auth can-i get storageclasses --as=system:serviceaccount:couchbase-dev:couchbase-operator-admission -n couchbase-dev
Warning: resource 'storageclasses' is not namespace scoped in group 'storage.k8s.io'
yes
```

it says yes.. what was the problem here.

Comment: Typo. `vshpere` vs `vsphere`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try check the spelling.

> Error from server: error when creating ...
>
> storage class "cpt-**vshpere**-with-tanzu-storage-policy" must exist
>
> ...

Your actual StorageClass name:

> NAME                                    PROVISIONER
>
> cpt-**vsphere**-with-tanzu-storage-policy   csi.vsphere.vmware.com